# Reflection on CLR C++ code with dotPeek

Tags: c#, reflection, c++-cli, dotpeek

I have this code written in CLR c++ :

```
namespace NS{
public class B {
public:
    B()
    {
        int k = 1 + 1;
    }
    static int K;
    int getId()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    static double getId2()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
}
```

I compile it to dll and use DotPeek and I am getting this result :

```
namespace NS
{
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[NativeCppClass]}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 1)]
public struct B
{
}
}
```

And also using C# reflection like this :

```
var module = Assembly.Load("MyCLRCPP").Modules.First();
foreach (var data in module.GetFields())
{
  Debug.WriteLine(data.Name);
 }
```

I get only some gibberish :

> __unep@?DoNothing@DefaultDomain@@@$$FCGJPAX@Z
>   __unep@?_UninitializeDefaultDomain@LanguageSupport@@@$$FCGJPAX@Z

My question is : 
**Why there is no code there?**

Comment: [NativeCppClass] should be a hint.  Your decompiler is not good enough to understand native C++ code, none of them are.  They can generally only tackle a `ref class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans said, there is a problem in decompiling native C++.
Using ref class solved everything.